# SharePoint online - hub site modern navigation - edit link not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience

As the title already suggests, there is no editing link for the global navigation on our hub site. As a SharePoint administrator I should have all the necessary privileges to do so.

If I add it through the classic experience - it won't show up in the modern view.

[image]

Comment: What'e the type of your site ? The picture you provided is communication site. Are you using commnunication site for hub site?

Comment: @MichaelHan_MSFT Yes indeed, we are using a communication site. I just found out, that it takes several hours for the navigation to show up. After editing/adding links in the classic experience, it will show up in the modern experience after about 2h. Problem solved.